# Compartilhamento Facebook em SPA

Tags: javascript, api, facebook

Boa tarde.

Estou com problemas de compartilhamento de post em um site SPA. 
Estou usando o seguinte código para tal:

```
FB.ui({
method: 'share_open_graph',
action_type: 'og.shares',
action_properties: JSON.stringify({
    object : {
       'og:url': 'url para acesso', 
       'og:title': 'titulo',
       'og:description': 'descricao',
       'og:image': 'imagem do post'
    }
})
},
// callback
function(response) {});
```

O problema está quando compartilho um post específico, o script não está buscando a imagem passada como parâmetro (no action_properties) mas sim a imagem que está especificada na meta tag do html principal.

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como resolver esse problema, pois a ideia é enviar a imagem do post selecionado para o compartilhamento (Pode haver vários post na mesma página).